# Accessing multiple dictionaries in list using for loop in Django Templates

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have been working on a project and it requires me to access dictionaries that are in a list. I am using Django 2.0. This is my code here.

```
{% if dictdata %}
    {% for x in range %}
        {{ "in loop" }}
        {{ dictdata.x.name }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ dictdata.0.name }}
    {{ dictdata.1.name }}
{% endif %}
```

The two statement after the for loop are working fine. But the one in the loop is not returning anything but printing the message 'in loop'. `dictdata`is a list containing dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what the value of your `range` varable is. So assuming `dictdata` is close to the following:

```
dictdata = [
    {'name': 'Bob'},
    {'name': 'John'}
]
```

You can loop over them in your template as follows:

```
{% for d in dictdata %}
    {{ d.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Documentation about looping in a template can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for).